# C++ Is this an "invalid" reference after returning?

Tags: c++, reference, scope, return

This is obviously bad:

```
int& GetInvalidIntPtr(){
   int i;
   return i;
}
```

This is my example:

```
FVector& GetDirectionFromCamera(){ 
   return GetActorLocation() - GetCameraComponent()->GetComponentLocation(); 
}
```

An FVector basically holds 3 floats, that is why I'd like to return the reference rather than a copy. However, I believe **the result of the calculation** is stored on the stack, right? 
Or is the result allocated on the heap because I am immediatly returning it?

Comment: It depends on signatures and behavior of functions and operators in second example. So, if they return reference to object created on heap you're OK. If not, you're not OK.

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what the `operator-` returns, but the right answer is simple: Return a copy, stop trying to optimise the tiny cost of copying three floats. [Keep It Simple, Stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An FVector basically holds 3 floats, that is why I'd like to return
>   the adress rather than a copy.

If you'd like to return an address, then why do you do return a reference instead? References are not pointers.

*(Deleted because the question has been modified to use the word "reference" instead of "address".)*

---

> However, I believe the result of the calculation is stored on the stack, right?

It really depends on what exactly your `operator-` returns. You don't show us, so we cannot know for sure, but if the operator simply returns `FVector` (as it should), then your code cannot compile, because a temporary `FVector` cannot be used to initialise an `FVector&`.

Generally, your code is based on the misconception that it's somehow bad to return a copy of an `FVector`. It is not. Change the function signature to `FVector GetDirectionFromCamera()` and let the compiler remove redundant copies.

> Or is the result allocated on the heap because I am immediatly returning it?

No. What you call "heap" only comes into play when you use dynamic allocation.

Comment: I changed adress to reference in my question. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

> Or is the result allocated on the heap because I am immediatly returning it?

What? How would that even happen?  The compiler does not just magically allocate things on the heap because you return something that's going out of scope.

Trying to optimise away a copy of three floats, at the risk of undefined behaviour because you don't understand what the code is really doing, is insanity. If you don't know any better then just return a copy. That's the simple and safe option. It's also likely to be the fastest, because simple code allows the compiler to optimise better.